# Как вывести список выбранных чекбоксов?

Tags: javascript

Привет всем. Дело вот в чем. У меня есть выпадаютщий список чекбоксов. Да именно чекбоксов. Дело в том что их около 10, и могут еще быть. Стилизованны все как надо. Мне надо сделать примерно так. Человек выбирает какой ни будь и у него сверху к примеру : Выбранные чекбоксы: ValueOfCheckbox1;ValueOfCheckbox5. Если человек убирает чекбокс из списка соответственно тоже убирается

[image: Как выглядит чекбоксы]

Comment: Не видно ваших попыток реализовать данный функционал. Приложите код к вопросу.

Comment: Как вариант скрыть блоки сверху и когда выбираешь чекбокс, то нужные блоки становились бы видимыми

Answer (score 2):

Если мозги есть - поймете и доведете до своего случая.
Другим тут не помочь

```js
var c = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');

var container = document.querySelector('ul.checked');

function buildList() {
  container.innerHTML = '';
  [].forEach.call(c, function(i) {
    if (i.checked) {
      var li = document.createElement('li');
      li.innerHTML = i.getAttribute('name');
      container.appendChild(li)
    }

  })
}

[].forEach.call(c, function(i) {
  i.onchange = buildList;
});
```

```html
<div>
  <input type='checkbox' name='1'>
  <input type='checkbox' name='2'>
  <input type='checkbox' name='3'>
</div>
<ul class='checked'>

</ul>
```

Comment: [внутри ul правильно только li, и  _script-supporting_ элементы (`script`,`template`)](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-ul-element)